# Counting Multi-Character Characters in String

Tags: c++, character, counter

For example, how do you count the occurrence of `"TJ"` in `OAEKOTJEOTJ`?

```
if (s[i] == 'TJ') and (s[i] == 'T'+'J')
    x += 1;
```

First one gives me an error, second one doesn't count. I need a beginner solution to this, I haven't learned very much about c++ commands yet. Thanks

```
int x = 0
string s;
cin >> s;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
if (s[i] == T || s[i] == t) && (s[i+1] == J || s[i+1] == j)
x += 1
cout << x << endl;
```

That's the excerpt from my code, it doesn't count any tj, tJ, Tj or TJ

Comment: Are you trying to find the substring `"TJ"` or are you actually talking about multi-character literals?

Comment: If it's actually the two characters, you can copy it into a `std::string`, loop each time you `string::find` it and `string::erase` it after you increase the counter.

Comment: Not sure what the difference is, I guess I'm trying to find the substring within the string. Like there are 2 TJs in that string I posted.

Comment: @Foxic, Multi-character literals aren't useful for much, if anything. Basically, you'd expect something like `'a'`, but `'ab'` (a multi-character literal) is also a valid construct.

Comment: The reason `'TJ'` doesn't work is that it's a multi-character literal. The reason `'T'+'J'` doesn't work is that adding two characters just gives a new character—in ASCII, the result is `'?'`. The third one is close, but you forgot the single quotes around the characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
if(s[i] == 'T' && s[i+1] == 'J') // and make sure you do not run out of bounds of string with index i.
x += 1;
```

EDIT:
Based on your code:

```
int x = 0
string s;
cin >> s;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
if (s[i] == T || s[i] == t) && (s[i+1] == J || s[i+1] == j)
x += 1
cout << x << endl;
```

You should do it like following:

```
int x = 0
string s;
cin >> s;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length()-1; i++) // use size of string s.length()-1 to iterate the string instead of 100
     if (s[i] == 'T' || s[i] == 't') && (s[i+1] == 'J' || s[i+1] == 'j') // compare the ascii values of characters like - 'T' 'J' etc.
         x += 1
cout << x << endl;
```

Comment: This looks for individual characters, the questions is about multi-characters.

Comment: what error are you getting... there are other ways to do this, but it would be good to understand what specifically your problem is, many people that can answer your question are making assumptions about the rest of your code which may not be correct, given that you are a self-proclaimed novice and most whom answer will not be

Comment: @Foxic : If you are using a string class, there are some functions you could use like `s.find("TJ")`etc.

Comment: s.find gives too big of a value for some reason

Comment: @Foxic, `string::find` returns the index it's found at. You can compare this value against `std::string::npos`, which means it wasn't found, in conjunction with increasing the index it was found at to begin the next search.

Comment: I'm too much of a beginner to know what that is :(

Comment: @Foxic, Well, the index is just the position in the string, and indices in C++ are zero-based, so 0 would be the beginning, 3 would be the fourth character, and 7 would be the eighth character. `npos` is just a constant that means, in this context, an invalid index, so if it's not found, it returns that invalid index. `find()` also lets you specify where in the string to start searching, so each time you find it, you can use the returned index to start searching just past that found one.

Comment: @Foxic: From your code it looks like you want to search in a case-insensitive manner. so, Using s.find() could be tricky here.

Comment: @srbh.kmr, Though it's easy enough to make your own: `std::transform(std::begin(s), std::end(s), tolower);`.

Comment: @chris: Yes, but then we will lose information what user inputted. In case application later on wants to use that. Unless we make a copy of `s`, of course.

Comment: @srbh.kmr, Oops, I forgot that `transform` has an output iterator. And yes, you could copy it if you need to use the case later (or use a new string as the output argument).

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` provides a function `find` which searches the string for substrings, including multi-character substrings (below, I am using C++11 syntax):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  string text { "OAEKOTJEOTJ" };
  unsigned int occ { 0 };
  size_t       pos { 0 };
  for (;;) {
    pos = text.find("TJ",pos);      // Search for the substring, start at pos
    if (pos == string::npos)        // Quit if nothing found
      break;
    ++pos;                          // Continue from next position
    ++occ;                          // Count the occurrence
  }
  std::cout << "Found " << occ << " occurrences." << std::endl;
}
```

The way it's done above we advance by one character only after each match. Depending on whether/how we want to deal with overlapping matches, we might want to advance `pos` by the length of the search pattern. (See chris's comment as well.)

Comment: I haven't learned any of this yet unfortunately, is there some easier way?

Comment: Wow, I completely forgot you can specify the starting position in `find`.

Comment: @Foxic If you don't / cannot use the `find` function, best go with srbh.kmr's approach.

Comment: His gives a bigger value, if I have 4 occurrences, itll say 7

Comment: @jogojapan, You might want to increase `pos` by 2, since you're finding two sequential characters. That one more comes down to if you're finding `aa` and you have `aaa` in the string - do you count it as one or two?

Comment: @chris I'd assumed it should be counted as two in this case (therefore increasing by one after each find). But yes, the idea of a more sophisticated (i.e. more efficient) algorithm would certainly be to analyse the string we are looking for and define a failure function that tells us how many characters we can advance after each mismatch, etc. And this would lead to the Knuth Morris Pratt algorithm (and similar).

Comment: @jogojapan, Interesting. I suppose it could work out whether or not it would create bad results; I was going off of the current example of two separate letters. I should get more into some of these algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <locale> // for tolower() function

string tolower(string s) {
  tolower(s[0]);
  tolower(s[1]);
  return s;
}
...
int main() {
  string s;
  cin >> s;
  int n = s.size(),cont = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < n ; ++i) {
    if(tolower(s.substr(i,2)) == "tj") {
      ++cont;
    }
  }
  cout << cont << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `substr`'s second parameter is the number of characters.

Comment: Won't this go out of bounds? i < n-2.

Comment: sorry, my mystake on the second parameter, and no ``s = "hello"; cout << s.substr(3,5);`` will output ``"lo"``

Comment: For your `tolower` function, you might as well use the `tolower` that's already implemented for characters.

Comment: Yes, I know, but maybe he doesn't know that function. Of course, perhaps he doesn't know ``substr`` function either, but who knows.

Comment: @hinafu, Personally, I think it would still be easier to read than ASCII-dependent code.