# How to count two characters in a string?

Tags: string, character, counting

There are three parameters (String s, char c, char d)

How do I define a method so that it returns as an int, the number of times the char c occurs in the String s added to the number of times the char d occurs in the String s?

Comment: That would depend, in part, on what language you were using.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617534/counting-multi-character-characters-in-string

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language, there could already be an existing function that does this for you.

Otherwise, you'd need to treat the string like an array (if the language does that, then great. If it doesn't, then you need to cast it into an array), run a loop and use a counter.  If you want to look for specific characters, you can pass that in a function along with the string/array).

Example (this is just psudo-code, since I don't know what language you're using):

```
function countCharsInString(string s, char c1, char c2)
{
 int count = 0;

 for(i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
 {
   if(s[i] == c1 || s[i] == c2)
   {
    count++;
   }
 }
 return count;
}
```